# call org-html-export-to-html from script failure

Tags: org-mode

I can run `org-html-export-to-html` on emacs successfully. but when I try to call it in script as below:

```
#!/usr/bin/emacs --script 
(require 'org)

(defun dired-org-to-html ()
  (let* ((org-root ".")
    (files
         (append
          (let ((default-directory org-root))
            (mapcar #'expand-file-name
                    (file-expand-wildcards "**/*.org")))
          (let ((default-directory org-root))
            (mapcar #'expand-file-name
                    (file-expand-wildcards "*.org")))
         )
         ))
    (mapc
     (lambda (f)
       (print f)
       (with-current-buffer
           (find-file-noselect f)
         (org-html-export-to-html)))
     files))
  )

(dired-org-to-html)
```

It always say `Symbol's function definition is void: org-html-export-to-html`.

Answer (score 2):

It works fine for me, still, you can try to include the ox-html in the top:

```lisp
#!/usr/bin/emacs --script 
(require 'org)
(require 'ox-html)


(defun dired-org-to-html ()
  (let* ((org-root ".")
    (files
         (append
          (let ((default-directory org-root))
            (mapcar #'expand-file-name
                    (file-expand-wildcards "**/*.org")))
          (let ((default-directory org-root))
            (mapcar #'expand-file-name
                    (file-expand-wildcards "*.org")))
         )
         ))
    (mapc
     (lambda (f)
       (print f)
       (with-current-buffer
           (find-file-noselect f)
         (org-html-export-to-html)))
     files))
  )

(dired-org-to-html)
```

It is the package where the function came from.

Comment: It's wired, it works on emacs, but when I run your version, I got below error: Cannot open load file: ox-html